# How do you find number of groups from a matrix that defines all the relationship between n points?

Tags: algorithm, greedy

Say, you have `n` points and a 2D matrix that gives the relationship between those points.
Now how do you parse it in such a way that you are able to count the number of groups that these `n` points form. Say if `1->2` and `2->3` then `1->3`. Assuming it's an undirected graph and each cell of the matrix defines if the elements at index `i` and `j`(both ways) are connected.
I'm struggling to intuitively understand how to look at problems like these, especially graph-related problems.

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) may be helpful.

Comment: You'll have to define exactly what you mean by "groups", and whether the relationships are one-way or two-way (i.e., do you have a directed or undirected graph)

Answer (score 0):

This is what's known as finding the [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms) of a graph, and can be done using either a breadth-first or depth-first search.